# ListView should be move upside while keyboard comes and list should show last entry at bottom

Tags: flutter

I am Trying to make notes..everything going well but I need a minor change.. I want like it whatsapp chat where sending message keyboard pushing list of messages upside and shows last msg at bottom..

Here is my code problem : I have taken column with only two widget ListView.builder and TextField.

while keyboard appears, list of notes are hide behind keyboard....that I don't want..listview should be move upside...

here is my demo coding

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late TextEditingController txtnote;
  List<String> notelist=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K'];
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    txtnote=TextEditingController();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Notes Example'),),
      body: MyBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget MyBody() {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: notelist.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return Card(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(notelist[index]),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 30.0,
                          child: Text(notelist[index][0]),),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      ),
                    );

              }),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: txtnote,
              onSubmitted: (value){
                setState(() {
                  notelist.add(value);
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

``
```

Comment: Can Anyone help..I need to solve urgent

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reverse` to make the last shown index still persist on the screen when the keyboard appears

Example:

```
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    reverse: true, // *here*
    itemCount: 10,
    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
         return Text('hello');
    }),
)
```